# Cannot seek value-initialized vector iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, assertion

My program fails when trying to increment a value in a while loop.
This is the error message:

> Expression: cannot seek value-initialized vector iterator

I thought it might have something to do with the return type of `vector.size()`, so I tried casting `it` to an `int`. Not even sure if that was a valid thing to consider.

```
int main() {

    std::cout << "Please enter a string to reverse followed by the # key: \n";
    std::vector<char> toReverse;
    char input = ' ';
    
    while (input != '#') 
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        toReverse.push_back(input);
    }


    std::vector<char>reversed{};

    std::copy_backward(toReverse.begin(), toReverse.end(), reversed.end());

    // check if it is a palindrome
    bool isPalindrome = false;
    int vectorLength{ 0 };
    //int(toReverse.size());

    while (vectorLength != (int)toReverse.size())
    {
            if (toReverse[vectorLength] == reversed[vectorLength]) 
            {
                isPalindrome = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
            ++vectorLength;
    }


    if (!isPalindrome)
    {
        std::cout << "reversed vector contains: ";
        for (auto i : reversed) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "You have entered a palindrome which is the same sequence when reversed!";
    }
}
```

I expected the while loop to run comparing the `toReverse` vector to the reversed vector if one of the positions does not equal the others' then `isPalindrome` will be set to `false` and the loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your usage of the `copy_backward()` function is riddled with fallacy as (from what I am assuming) you are attempting to reverse the order of the elements inputted by the user via copying the elements to a new container in the reverse order starting from the end of the new container, which is nugatory in reversing the original order as the `copy_backward()` function merely copies the elements to the specified container in the reverse order rather than actually reversing the order of the elements.

Secondly, as for the actual source of the error, the container which you are copying to (`reversed`) is empty which makes it too small to store any passed data, triggering an undefined behavior.

Using the function `reverse_copy()` will resolve your problem regarding the reversal of the order of elements and the function `back_inserter()` will allow you to add elements to an empty container as it constructs an iterator which can be used to add elements towards the end of the container.

Replace your `copy_backward()` function call with the following function call: `std::reverse_copy(toReverse.begin(), toReverse.end(), std::back_inserter(reversed))`.

Furthermore, the pound (`#`) character in your input is not filtered from the elements stored in the `toReverse` container (which, as per my assumption, must be filtered). Add a condition like `if (input != '#')` before adding the element to the `toReverse` container.